# What is a bus bar in an electrical switch board?

Tags: electrical, electrical-distribution

I am doing some research in electrical wiring and mains switch boards and was wondering what a bus bar is and what it does?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think [Wikipedia](http://www.wikipedia.org/) can explain what a [bus bar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busbar) is, better than I can. But in general terms. It's a strip of conductive material where other conductors can connect, to safely interconnect all the conductors.

If you look in an empty single split phase electrical panel, you'll see 3 or 4 bus bars. Two ungrounded (hot) bus bars running down the middle, one grounded (neutral) bus bar off to the side or at top/bottom, and one grounding bus bar off to the side or at top/bottom.

[image: Labeled Electrical Panel]